Error al intentar agregar anotación a pdf con add_annotation
Estoy intentando insertar un número de folio en una hoja específica de un archivo pdf usando PyPDF2, pero al ejecutar el código se me presenta el error:
AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'

El código es el siguiente:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import NameObject, TextStringObject, DictionaryObject, NumberObject
from typing import Dict, Any

reader = PdfReader('D:/paises/solicitud.pdf')
writer = PdfWriter()

for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
    writer.add_page(reader.pages\[page_num\])

folio = DictionaryObject()
folio.update({
    NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
    NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/Text"),
    NameObject("/Rect"): \[NumberObject(100), NumberObject(100), NumberObject(200), NumberObject(200)\],
    NameObject("/Contents"): TextStringObject("Folio: 000001"),
    NameObject("/P"): writer.pages\[0\],  
    NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)  
    })

writer.add_annotation(0,folio)

with open('D:/paises/solicitud_OK.pdf','wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)

El error se general al intentar escribir el archivo con la instrucción writer.write(fp).
Lo que pretendo es que la anotación se quede permanente en el archivo y que se pueda imprimir.
Cabe aclarar que en otro programa que realicé (adjunto código) se integra la anotación al pdf, sin embargo, al imprimirlo la anotación no se imprime:
def folioArchivo(e):
     global folder_path
     pdf_path=folder_path
     #print("Hola")
     #pdf_path = seleccionar_archivo()
     reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
     writer=PdfWriter()
     texto=""
     pos=pdf_path.index('.')
     archivo=pdf_path[:pos]+"_fol.pdf"
     numPag = len(reader.pages)
     numDig = len(str(numPag))
     for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
         page= reader.pages[page_num]
         writer.add_page(page)
         texto=pagina(numDig,page_num+1)
         anotacion = PyPDF2.generic.AnnotationBuilder.free_text(texto,rect = [555, 720,585, 735],font="Book Antiqua", bold=True,
                                                        font_size="70pt", font_color="000000")
         writer.add_annotation(page_number=page_num, annotation=anotacion)

     with open(archivo, "wb") as fp:
         writer.write(fp)

Edición
Aplicando la solución de la respuesta el error se solucionó. Ahora lo que sucede es que la anotación se me repite en todo el documento; es decir, el folio va cambiando, pero al escribir la anotación sucede que se queda con la última. El documento tiene 50 páginas y el todos aparece el folio 50. Este es el código actual:
def folioArchivo(e):
     global folder_path
     pdf_path=folder_path
     reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
     writer=PdfWriter()
     texto=""
     pos=pdf_path.index('.')
     archivo=pdf_path[:pos]+"_fol.pdf"
     numPag = len(reader.pages)
     numDig = len(str(numPag))
     folio = DictionaryObject()
     folio.update({
     NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
     NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/FreeText"),
     NameObject("/Rect"): RectangleObject([NumberObject(555), NumberObject(720), NumberObject(585), NumberObject(735)]),
     NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)
        })
     for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
         page = reader.pages[page_num]
         writer.add_page(page)
         texto=pagina(numDig,page_num+1)
         folio.update({
         NameObject("/Contents"): TextStringObject(texto),
         NameObject("/P"): page
                     })
         writer.add_annotation(page_num,folio)
    
     with open(archivo, "wb") as fp:
         writer.write(fp)




No conozco el paquete, pero teniendo en cuenta el error y mirando un poco la documentación, parece que el problema está en:
NameObject("/Rect"): [NumberObject(100), NumberObject(100), NumberObject(200), NumberObject(200)],

Básicamente espera que la clave sea un objeto  RectangleObject pero le pasas una lista directamente. Simplemente:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import (
    NameObject,
    TextStringObject,
    DictionaryObject,
    NumberObject,
    RectangleObject  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
)

reader = PdfReader('D:/paises/solicitud.pdf')
writer = PdfWriter()
writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
    
padd = len(str(len(writer.pages))) + 1
for page_num, page in enumerate(writer.pages):
    annotation = DictionaryObject({
        NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
        NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/FreeText"),
        NameObject("/Rect"): RectangleObject(  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            [NumberObject(100), NumberObject(100),
             NumberObject(200), NumberObject(200)]
        ),
        NameObject("/Contents"): TextStringObject(f"Folio: {page_num + 1 : 0{padd}}"),
        NameObject("/P"): page, 
        NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)  
    })
    writer.add_annotation(page_number=page_num, annotation=annotation)


with open('D:/paises/solicitud_OK.pdf', 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)

Si quieres mostrar el texto  y que se imprima debes cambiar el tipo de la anotación a "FreeText". "Text" muestra un bocadillo/globo con el texto desplegable.

Nota: ten en cuenta que PyPDF2 se a vuelto a unir con el proyecto original y actualmente se desarrolla bajo el nombre pypdf de nuevo:
History: pypdf: Back to the Roots (2023-Today)
PyPdf2 es por tanto una versión antigua, considera usar pypdf ya que tendrás la versión mas reciente, simplemnete instalalo (python -m pip install pypdf) y para este código solo cambia los imports:
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from pypdf.generic import (...)


Edición
Ten en cuenta que si haces esto:
 folio = DictionaryObject()
 folio.update({
     NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
     NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/FreeText"),
     NameObject("/Rect"): RectangleObject([
         NumberObject(555), NumberObject(720),
         NumberObject(585), NumberObject(735)
     ]),
     NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)
 })

 for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
     page = reader.pages[page_num]
     writer.add_page(page)
     texto = pagina(numDig,page_num+1)
     folio.update({
         NameObject("/Contents"): TextStringObject(texto),
         NameObject("/P"): page
     })
     writer.add_annotation(page_num, folio)

Estás agregando el mismo objeto DictionaryObject como anotación a todas las páginas. dict.update() actualiza el diccionario in-place a partir del diccionario recibido como argumento, no genera un nuevo objeto. Al final tendrás la misma anotacion en todas las páginas y con los datos agregados en la última iteración, que es la última modificación del objeto.
Para cada anotación distinta debes crear un nuevo objeto DictionaryObject:
for page_num, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    writer.add_page(page)
    texto = pagina(numDig, page_num + 1)
    folio = DictionaryObject({
        NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
        NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/FreeText"),
        NameObject("/Rect"): RectangleObject([
            NumberObject(555), NumberObject(720),
            NumberObject(585), NumberObject(735)
        ]),
        NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)
        NameObject("/Contents"): TextStringObject(texto),
        NameObject("/P"): page
    })
    writer.add_annotation(page_num, folio)
    

O también realizar una copia del objeto, en este caso con una copia superficial basta:
folio_base = DictionaryObject({
    NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
    NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/FreeText"),
    NameObject("/Rect"): RectangleObject([
        NumberObject(555), NumberObject(720),
        NumberObject(585), NumberObject(735)
    ]),
    NameObject("/F"): NumberObject(4)
})

for page_num, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    writer.add_page(page)
    texto = pagina(numDig, page_num + 1)
    folio = folio_base.copy()
    folio[NameObject("/Contents")] = TextStringObject(texto)
    folio[NameObject("/P")] = page
    writer.add_annotation(page_num, folio)


Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Efectivamente, con lo que me indicaste pasé ese error.

ahora lo que sucede es que la anotación se me repite en todo el documento; es decir, el folio va cambiando, pero al escribir la anotación sucede que se queda con la última. El documento tiene 50 páginas y el todos aparece el folio 50.

Integré el código que estoy utilizando para insertar una anotación (folio) en cada página, pero no encuentro la razón de que al final todas las páginas del documento tienen el último folio (50). De favor me puedes apoyar a determinar el por qué de tal situación.

@EnriqueMontoya Hola, tienes que crear un nuevo DictionaryObject para cada anotación (o hacer una copia del mismo y modificar los valores necesarios). Si no lo haces así estarás incluyendo la misma anotación en todas las páginas. He editado la respuesta y modificado el código de ejemplo. Básicamente es incluir un bucle que itere sobre cada página del pdf de destino e ir creando su anotación propia para cada una.  No puedo probarlo ahora mismo pero debería funcionar sin problemas.

FJSevilla, muchas gracias por tu enorme apoyo. Realicé el ajuste como lo indicas y efectivamente en cada página del PDF ya se inserta el folio correspondiente. Muchas gracias de nuevo y saludos.
